# Trying to plot mm:ss as the independent variable on the X-Axis, but Excel treats it as hours and a 24 hour cycle

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am doing a report for a company I work for that tracks call data in relation to other number data. Calls are measured in terms of mm:ss, but when I try to do this format, it either misreads the numbers and states it as a decimal, or it treats it as a time with reference to AM or PM.

Does anyone know how I can convert this data to mm:ss (data appears in Excel like 14:32, 10:04, 5:14, 30:54 etc), so that I can accurately and properly plot this in a scatter plot? I am trying to do a linear regression on this but since the x axis is treating the time in a 24 hour interval, I am unable to properly deal with this issue.

Does anyone have any sort of suggestion for me? Thank you.

Comment: Please show us some sample data and a mock-up of the chart you want. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: What if you format the cell to `mm:ss` but enter the data in the `00:00:00`format?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber  I apparently I took what you said and then  suffered verbal diarrhea with my explanation of it

Comment: If the data is being interpreted as HH;MM, divide it by 60 and format it to show MM:SS. Even better, use a number format of [MM]:SS, so the minutes go beyond 60 if it's more than an hour.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here, but I think you need a basic understanding of how excel deals with date and time.  You issue is mainly the later, but I find a general understanding can help out in unexpected ways at times.

Date and Time in excel are stored as numbers.  A quick test to see if your data is properly stored or if it is a string masquerading as number is perform a quick test on it.  Lets assume your data is in B13.  You could use the following equations:

```
=ISNUMBER(B13)

=ISTEXT(B13)
```

That is usually half the battle right there...ensuring your data is in the right format.

The next part is understanding how that information is stored. The Date is an integer representing the number of days since January 1 1900, (potentially 1905 on a mac) with January 1st 1900 being  day 1.  Since days are the integer, that means that decimal are portions of a day or better known as time.  0.5 is noon.  As a result your time if entered as actual minutes and seconds will be some weird looking decimal.  Its excels cell formatting that will take that weird decimal and make it look like something understandable.

You can either apply the standard time format to the cell which will five you AM/PM type format usually.  You can also apply custom formatting to a cell to display the time in a way you want.  Bellow is a screen shot showing the same time with different custom cell formats applied to it.  The time in the left column and the format used in the right column.

[image: sample formats]

If you have a column (Assume B13:B20) with your time stored as text in the format mm:ss  that can easily be converted using the following formula placed in C13 and copied down as required:

```
=TIME(0,--LEFT(B13,FIND(":",B13)-1),--RIGHT(B13,LEN(B13)-FIND(":",B13)))
```

Basically TIME is looking for three entries,  TIME(HOURS,MINUTES,SECONDS) where HOURS, MINUTES, SECONDS are numbers.  Using LEFT and RIGHT, the minutes and seconds would be pulled from the string and converted to a number by the --.  Note any math operation on a number stored as a string will convert it to number.  Therefore +0,-0, *1, and /1 would have worked as well.

If you are performing the data entry yourself, you have a few options.  1 would be to prefix your time with ' which will indicate to excel that you are entering text.  when you are done use the above formula to convert your numbers as text to a usable time format.

A better method would be to enter your time in the format hh:mm:ss or 0:90:15.  The leading 0: will allow excel to automatically distinguish your time in the right units.  When you are done, you can apply custom formatting to the cell to make the time display as you like.